# bash string manipulation on a computed variable?

Tags: bash

I'm looking for a the simplest one-instruction solution to manipulate a computed string.
For example, removing the last two characters on a computed string: md5sum returns with ' -'  at the end.

I can do it in two instructions:

```
$ a=$(echo 'ab'|md5sum); a=$(echo ${a:0:-2})
$ echo $a # (not required instruction)
daa8075d6ac5ff8d0c6d4650adb4ef29
```

How do I do it with one instruction, like the following?

```
$ a=${(echo 'ab'|md5sum):0:-2}
-bash: ${(echo 'ab'|md5sum):0:-2}: bad substitution
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the point? The second assignment is totally within the shell (`echo` is a builtin). A real thing to do better is `a="${a:0:-2}"` instead of `a=$(echo ${a:0:-2})`.

Comment: Bash doesn't have nested parameter expansion, so you'll have to use something else. Maybe just `read a _ < <(echo ... | md5sum)`? But anyway, I agree with @KamilMaciorowski there's not much point to forcing this into one command.

Comment: in zsh, you could do `a=${"$(echo 'abcxx')":0:-2}`, but other shells don't support nested expansions like that. (There's some oddity there where it requires the quotes to treat the command substitution output as a single string instead something split to a list. Of course you could also utilize that with the output of `md5sum`.)

Comment: @ Kamil Maciorowski - thank you for the code without the echo.                                    

@ muru - thank you for the answer I was looking for, that Bash doesn't have nested parameter expansion.                                    

@ ilkkachu - thanks for suggesting zsh. I always want to learn the better dialect, but sadly, don't have the time!.                                    

@ Chris Davies - thanks for your efforts and explanation

Comment: `echo 'ab' | md5sum` will give you the hash of `ab\n`, not the hash of `ab`. You should probably be doing `printf 'ab' | md5sum` instead so a `\n` isn't being added to the `md5sum` input, depending on how you're using the resulting hash.

Comment: Please clarify that you need to delete 3 trailing chars, not 2, since the output of `md5sum` is [the checksum, a space, a flag indicating binary or text input mode, and the file name. Binary mode is indicated with ‘*’, text mode with ‘ ’ (space)](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cksum-output-modes.html). On my system I see `<sum><blank>*-` while apparently on the OPs system they must currently see `<sum><blank><blank>-`.

Comment: @ Ed Morton - thank you for pointing out these details as the devil is in the details of all coding! I appreciate you help!

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly you could use this:

```
a=$(echo 'ab' | md5sum)
a=${a%??}
```

Result in `$a` is `daa8075d6ac5ff8d0c6d4650adb4ef29`

You could omit the second assignment if you're just going to be using `${a%??}`, but unless you're going to use it immediately I'd advise against this. (As coding style goes it would separate the two parts of generating the required value, and that in turn would create a fragile association that can make code maintenance more difficult.)

To do this in one assignment would be possible, but marginally less efficient:

```
a=$(echo 'ab' | md5sum | sed 's/..$//')
```

Be aware that in both cases, `echo 'ab'` will include the trailing newline in the MD5 checksum. You might want to use `echo -n 'ab'`, or more portably `printf '%s' 'ab'`.